# Wrong rendering - \sqrt interesting shape (\sqrt not slanted)

Tags: math-mode

Unfortunately I'm not able to provide a MWE, because this error apparently is not reproduceable in another document

As you can see in the picture, the upper sqrt is somehow tilted...

There is nothing in the log related to this part.

Any idea, what this could be?

```
\documentclass[
titlepage,
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
oneside,
%   bibtotoc,
%   listof=nochaptergap,
final  % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} %Mathe Umgebung

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
I_{max}&=  \sqrt{\dfrac{P_{nom}-\frac{P_{nom}}{T_{max}-T_{nom}}
\cdot(T_{max}-T_{amb})}{R}} \label{gl:resis-power1}\\
I_{max}&= \sqrt{\dfrac{P_{nom}-\frac{P_{nom}}{155^\circ C-70^\circ C}\cdot(155^\circ C-T_{amb})}{R}} \label{gl:resis-power2}

\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the top example, the numerator is bigger because of the subscripts, so TeX has to choose a larger radical, which turns out to be the “composed” one, made up with vertical pieces.

Comment: i can't reproduce your result. both square root has equal shape. only top one is slightly taller.

Comment: The radicals are as expected but note you should not use math italic for words such as max (unless they mean m times a times x) use `_{\mathrm{max}}`

Comment: or simple `\max` :)

Comment: @Zarko Unfortunately, `\max` is semantically wrong in this context.  `\max` is a mathematical operator whereas the index `\mathrm{max}` is merely a descritpion, consider e.g. `x_{\mathrm{max}} = \max_x f(x)`.

Comment: @Marcel Could you please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or at least tell what document class (plus other options/commands to change the font size) you are using? I'm trying with different classes and font sizes, but I'm not able to reproduce your output.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I agree that `\max` used for index is not semantically correct, but is appearance of `x_{\max}` differ from `x_{\mathrm{max}}`?

Comment: @Zarko Yes, if `\operator@font` and `\mathrm` differ.

Comment: @siracusa now I was able to produce a MWE :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the hint, I'll try to improve my formulas in the future (I used to use `\mathrm` in the past, but I became to lazy after a while... )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you show is entirely expected.  Math fonts have a fixed number of "designed" symbols in a range of sizes (where the left of the radical is sloped, and parentheses are curved). But then (depending on the font and the symbol being displayed) at some point there are no symbols of that size available and so it switched to a "constructed" symbol made up of glyph parts and a necessarily straight vertical extension symbol repeated as often as necessary.

[image]

In this case the subscript `T_{\mathrm{nom}}` in the numerator just fractionally increased the height of the fraction and forced Tex to switch the method of displaying the square root .

Comment: At the bottom we see a nice visualization of the Doppler effect, as demonstrated by a tiny x travelling to the left while yelling the number 2.